# mysqli_multi_query array issue

Tags: php, jquery, mysqli

There's something weird going on.
I have I database which could look something like this:

```
table name: dm
|id|receiver|sender|msg          |
|1 |John    |Emma  |Hey John!    |
|2 |Emma    |John  |Hey!         |
|3 |John    |Emma  |Whats up     |
|4 |Emma    |John  |Not too much |
|5 |John    |Keira |Have you got...|
```

I have an html page with a  on it and for now what I want is for the messages that either

1. Emma sent to John => receiver = "John", sender = "Emma" or
2. John sent to Emma => receiver = "Emma", sender = "John"

to be displayed in the console.
I can do that with JQuery using the console.log() function.

My PHP looks like this:

```
$user1 = "John";
$user2 = "Emma";
$sql = "SELECT * FROM dm WHERE receiver = '$user1' AND sender = '$user2';SELECT * FROM dm WHERE receiver = '$user2' AND sender = '$user1'";

// Execute multi query
if (mysqli_multi_query($link,$sql))
{
  do
    {
      $i = 0;
      $msg = array();

    if ($result=mysqli_store_result($link)) {

      while ($row=mysqli_fetch_row($result))
        {
        printf("%s\n",$row[0]);
        $msg[$i] = $row[0];
          $i++;
        }
      mysqli_free_result($result);
      }
    }
  while (mysqli_next_result($link));
}

echo json_encode($msg);
exit();
mysqli_close($link);
```

You will notice, that I have "printf" in there, because I wanted to see what the databse would give back to me. It correctly gave back the id's: 1,3,2,4.

However, I normally would like to do the request using JQuery ajax. I know how to do that also. Because of that I want to have an array which holds all the id's of the posts like this:

```
["1","2","3","4"]
```

Unfortunately the way I do it as written in the code what it returns to me is this:

```
["2","4"]
```

So what's going on is that he only puts what was in the first query into the array.

So what exactly is my question?

I want to fix the array to hold *all* the id's of the respective messages which would be 1,2,3,4. Preferably in this order as well and not like this 1,3,2,4.

I hope I made the problem clear and thank you for any advice!

Comment: Where is your jQuery part?

Comment: not neccessary here. The problem lies somewhere in the php. I can tell, because when I click on the button and get redirected to the php page (so no ajax request) it shows me ' 1 3 2 4 ["2","4"] '. The jquery part would just handle the json_encode($msg) bit.

Comment: You are wide open to [**SQL injection**](https://www.owasp.org/index.php/SQL_Injection). You need to use prepared statements, rather than concatenating variables into your query. See [How can I prevent SQL injection in PHP?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/60174/how-can-i-prevent-sql-injection-in-php?rq=1).

Comment: can't you only do a `$msg[] = $row[0]` without the `$i` in it? I don't see any difference...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You reset `$i` and `$msg` inside the outer loop. That means you will only see results from the second query in your array. Move the `$i = 0;` and `$msg = array();` lines outside that loop.

That said, there’s no reason to do 2 queries here. Just use an `OR` in your `WHERE` clause to get both results at once. This will be faster and easier.

Also, this is very important: you are wide open to [**SQL injection**](https://www.owasp.org/index.php/SQL_Injection). You need to use prepared statements, rather than concatenating variables into your query. See [How can I prevent SQL injection in PHP?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/60174/how-can-i-prevent-sql-injection-in-php?rq=1).

Comment: And how would I do that? What I need is for the receiver and Sender to be „fixed“. So either Emma AND James or James AND Emma.

Comment: @D.Krold What do you mean? I’ve told you in my answer exactly how to solve the problem: move those two lines of code to outside your `do ... while` loop. That is the answer to your question as asked. If you wanted something different, you should accept this answer and then ask a new question.

Comment: Okay mate, relax.

Comment: If you’re asking about the SQL query, it should be one query with a `WHERE` clause like `WHERE receiver = '$user1' AND sender = '$user2' OR receiver = '$user2' AND sender = '$user1'`. (This is just for illustration. As I said, you have a SQL injection problem, and you need to use placeholders and prepared statements rather than concatenating variables directly into your query.)

Comment: Thank you, that’s great @Ed Cottrell